# mapping from camera/Image-raw to kinect RGB-D

Tags: ros-hydro, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every body
I'm working on follow-me task. The goal is to make a turtle-bot-like robot follow a specific person in the crowd. I use [skeleton_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers) to find joints of target person's body and with some control procedure follow her/him.
To better support the gained information from *skeleton_markers*, I want to know how to find corresponding pixel(s) of a specific joint, so I will be able to extract some visual features to uniquely identify the followed person in the crowd.

Concisely, what is the x-y (in pixel) of a joint (that *skeleton_markers* has published) so I can draw a bounding-box around it. And also in case of losing the followed person (for example due to changing pose), I want to have an approximate place -based on the aforementioned bounding-box- to look for the person in that area.

Can somebody tell any package or method/procedure to achieve this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
P.S.: I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
P.P.S: Packages like [OpenTLD](https://github.com/pandora-auth-ros-pkg/open_tld) can follow a textured, but I can't find a way to hint the *skeleton_markers* package to search a specific place to find the person in case of losing her/him.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203199/mapping-from-camera/image-raw-to-kinect-rgb-d/) by [Ho'jat Kaveh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21651/ho%27jat-kaveh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm using hydro and pcl to do this. But i'm not able yet to set the spesific person to be followed. As far as i know point cloud has no task like you wrote. Have you done this? With skeleton_markers?

---

Originally posted by [Karz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22805/karz/) with karma: 16 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ho'jat Kaveh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21651/ho%27jat-kaveh/) on 2015-09-19**:
I'm sorry to inform you that in the end I couldn't solve the problem using *skeleton_markers* in ROS and switched to Microsoft package on windows. As recall my main *unsolved* problem was that I couldn't find a transformation matrix from/to depth space to/from color space.

**Comment by [Karz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22805/karz/) on 2015-09-20**:
Ok no problem.. thank you for your answer

Cheers :)